# How to use CNAME to properly redirect subdomain from host to Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage, cname, bucket

I have outlined my issue below in list format for clarity:

1. I have a subdomain named `clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com`
2. I used a CNAME record to redirect the subdomain to `c.storage.googleapis.com`
3. On Google Cloud, I have a bucket named `clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com` (exactly the same as the subdomain
4. I uploaded html files, a css file, and some various text files to make up a resume website into the bucket with the exact same file path as in my host
5. When I go to clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com in my browser, the error "Invalid Bucket Name" appears, and the URL changes to simply `c.storage.googleapis.com`
6. Why is the bucket name invalid - shouldn't it be exactly like the subdomain name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To use your bucket as a static site you need to configure it first using gsutil:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

You probably need to upload an index.html and 404.html to your bucket and then run this:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I looked into the instruction website you sent me, but I'm still a little confused at how to incorporate the code from the gsutil, the JSON API, or the XML API into the existing bucket and change its properties. How would I take the code, for example, to configure the main page/error page in the XML API and actually apply it? I can't seem to understand it from the instructions Google provides. I'm sorry, I'm dreadfully new to Google Cloud, and cloud services in general.

Comment: Ah ok. Don't worry about the json or xml api. Using gsutil is the easiest, the other 2 are just alternatives. gsutil is a command line tool that you can download and then you just type the gsutil command I showed above. See here for more info: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a CNAME redirect. Instead, you're using an HTTP 301 Redirect.

The DNS entry "clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com" has a DNS A record resolving to some nginx server somewhere. That server takes in HTTP requests and responds with a 301 Redirect to http://c.storage.googleapis.com/.

A CNAME redirect works differently. Instead of using a web server, there is a DNS entry that says "this DNS name is equivalent to this other DNS name." The client sees this when it looks up the DNS record and goes straight to the second source.

Comment: How would I use the latter? MY host requires me to enter a name and a CNAME. For name, I believe I enter my subdomain.domain.com. What would I enter for CNAME if I don't want to go through a third party as in your first description?

Comment: You don't need a host. You need only a domain name and the ability to set DNS records on that domain. There needs to be a CNAME DNS entry on the domain "clouddemo.camerontaylor94.com" that has the value "c.storage.googleapis.com".  Right now, that subdomain does not appear to have any DNS records other than a single A record.